# how to parse in angularjs and take all values

Tags: angularjs

{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
"GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
"GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
"SortAs": "SGML",
"GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
"Acronym": "SGML",
"Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
"GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create
markup languages such as DocBook.",
"GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
"GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: how to pass this json in angularjs

Comment: What do you mean by passing???
add a description

Comment: how are this values are going to fetch..please update a question with more info.

Comment: give me the example json parse in angularjs

Comment: use this function https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

Comment: how to pass this value and display it in table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this come from a file or maybe a distant URL you can get this content with the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) : the content will be automaticaly convert in JSON if possible :

```
$http.get('/someUrl').success(function(jsonValue){
    console.log(jsonValue)
});
```